# Is there a way to include an armv6 lib in an armv7 project?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcodebuild

I have an iPhone project in xcode that needs to be compiled for **armv7** architecture. I recently needed to include a library that I only have compiled for **armv6**.

**Is there a way to include an armv6 lib in an armv7 project?**

additional notes:

- The project really has to be compiled in armv7.
- I can't recompile the armv6 library to armv7 (closed source).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer to your question is **no**. You can include the static library compiled for **armv6** architecture in your project, but it will never link correctly when you build for **armv7**. The only solution seems to be to get the library sources and build it for **armv7** yourself, but I see this is not possible in your case. I had a similar problem recently, I asked the library owner to build it in the architecture that I required, and they did. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work, but it might. When people build universal frameworks for others to use, they build the i386 and armv6/7 libraries separately, then they combine them using lipo. I'm wondering if you could build an armv6 library and an armv7 library seperately and then use the same technique. ie. the lipo command.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but only in certain controllable circumstances.

1. If you don't have access to the source, is there a more current version of the library that does include armv7?
2. Ask the source or the developer to add support for armv7.
3. If all else fails, is there a better way to do it and not use this older (and obviously unsupported) library?

Comment: I still say it is not possible. None of the points that you mention actually do what rahzark wants, which is link the library built for armv6 architecture with the project build for armv7.

Comment: @lawicko Yes, you are right. If any of these points was possible it would be perfect, but unfortunately it's out of my reach :( Anyway, thank you all for confirmation on this!